How to Create a Grading Grid System for Students in Spring Boot and React
I'm working on a grading grid system with microservice  for students in my project using Spring Boot (backend) and React (frontend). I need help with implementing the following:
Problem:
Grille Creation: I want to create a grading grid (called "grille") for each student. Each grid contains different criteria that need to be graded by the academic supervisor (Encadrant Académique).
Supervisor Dashboard: When an academic supervisor logs into their dashboard, they should see:
A list of students
A grading grid (grille) for each student
The ability to add notes (grades) for each criterion in the grid.
What I Have So Far:
I'm using Spring Boot to handle backend APIs and React for the frontend.
I already have a list of students and have created entities like Grille and Critere in my Spring Boot backend.
Each Grille is associated with a Student and contains various Critere that the supervisor needs to grade.
What I Need Help With:
How to structure the API endpoints for listing all grading grids (grilles) per student, and allowing the academic supervisor to submit grades (notes) for each criterion.
Best practices for displaying the list of students and grids in the supervisor's React dashboard, with the ability to assign grades.
Any recommendations for CRUD operations for managing the grids and criteria, especially associating grids with students.
Backend Setup (Spring Boot):
I have the following entities:
Student: Represents the student
Grille: Represents the grading grid
Critere: Represents the criteria that need to be graded in the grid
Note: Represents the grade assigned to each criterion in the grid
Frontend Setup (React):
I have a basic dashboard for academic supervisors where I need to list all the students and their grading grids.
I need help creating a form or table where the supervisor can enter grades for each criterion in the grid.
Any guidance, code snippets, or resources would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
Backend:
I created the following Spring Boot entities: Student, Grille, Critere, and Note.
I implemented basic CRUD operations for managing students and grids (using JpaRepository).
I have an API that lists all students and grids, but I’m having trouble figuring out how to structure it so that the academic supervisor can add grades (notes) to each criterion in a specific grid.
I'm using a @ManyToOne relationship between Grille and Student, and between Grille and Critere. For Note, I’m using a @ManyToOne relationship to link each grade to the Critere.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
